# Running DUnit tests from Hudson

Tags: delphi, continuous-integration, hudson, delphi-xe

I finally got Hudson to build my project and the corresponding test project (using the XMLTestRunner2 unit provided in the Embarcadero forum). Running the test executable manually correclty produces a "dunit-report.xml" file with the test results.

I can't get Hudson to call my executable and produce this file though.

What I did is to create a build step as a Windows batch command and just call the executable. I tried several things:

```
bin\Test.exe
start bin\Test.exe
start /wait bin\Test.exe
start /wait /b bin\Test.exe
```

I cannot get it to work. It either returns immediately with some random exit code or it does not produce the XML output file. This must be very simple but I'm a little bit frustrated by now, because I don't get it to work.

What's the right way to execute the unit tests from Hudson?

Comment: is there no information in the Hudson screen "Console output" for the job?

Comment: @mjn: no, just that the xunit result file was not found.

Comment: I would try a simple test batch, something like `echo something > test.txt` and see where the output is - or use Apache Ant to create the build scripts, it is fully supported by Hudson and writes clear error information

Comment: Has your Hudson instance been started as a Windows service and you're trying to run DUint GUI test runner?

Comment: good point. That's not the case but it might have something to do with the fact that I'm using runtime packages. Maybe some runtime package is missing. I have to check...